# polygon lighthouse graphql type

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, polygon, laravel-lighthouse

I am using lighthouse PHP in my laravel 5.7 application. I'm trying to define an geometric field(polygon) in my schema, but it didn't work well.

Can anyone help me how to define the polygon field in my graphql schema.
[schema and query code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSsYE.png)

Comment: Could you add the code you have so far to your question?

Comment: yes ok done @digijay

Comment: Where is your type definition for polygon? What errors are you getting?
I think you should look at [Scalars](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/scalars.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to your image you have not created a type for `Polygon`.

As you haven't really specified how you would like to illustrate a polygon I am just going to show an example. In this example I am going to create a new GraphQl Scalar type.

A common way to specify a polygon is with a set of sets of coordinates like so

```
((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))
```

To represent this I would create a new Scalar

```
"A string representation of a polygon e.g. `((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))`."
scalar Polygon @scalar(class: "Your\\Classname\\Polygon")
```

Then create the class which has to parse/validate the string

```
use GraphQL\Error\Error;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\Node;
use GraphQL\Language\AST\StringValueNode;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ScalarType;

class Polygon extends ScalarType
{

    /**
     * Serializes an internal value to include in a response.
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     *
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws Error
     */
    public function serialize($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Geometry\Polygon) {
            $value->toString();
        }

        return (new Geometry\Polygon($value))->toString();
    }

    /**
     * Parses an externally provided value (query variable) to use as an input
     *
     * In the case of an invalid value this method must throw an Exception
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     *
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws Error
     */
    public function parseValue($value)
    {
        return new Geometry\Polygon($value);
    }

    /**
     * Parses an externally provided literal value (hardcoded in GraphQL query) to use as an input
     *
     * In the case of an invalid node or value this method must throw an Exception
     *
     * @param Node         $valueNode
     * @param mixed[]|null $variables
     *
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function parseLiteral($valueNode, ?array $variables = null)
    {
        if (! $valueNode instanceof StringValueNode) {
            throw new Error(
                "Query error: Can only parse strings, got {$valueNode->kind}",
                [$valueNode]
            );
        }

        return new Geometry\Polygon($valueNode->value);
    }
}
```

I have not implemented the logic for the `Geometry\Polygon` class and all the validation for this type of input and the Scalar type might need some tweaking also. But this is basically how you would create the Polygon Scalar type in Ligthouse.

Having this, you can then in your `areazone` field input a string with the format specified above and in your code you will get it as a `Geometry\Polygon` class.

You can read more about scalars in [Lighthouse docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/scalars.html).